# conda creating environments. Parameter choice

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

The documentation for `conda` has [the following example](http://docs.continuum.io/conda/intro.html):

```
$ conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
```

My question is, why do we specify `anaconda` as an argument here? (what other options are available and what are the differences)?

Is `anaconda` here a meta-package? If so, what other metapackages are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the help, `anaconda` in that example installs the package spec `anaconda`.

Comment: Is that what a `meta-package` is called? How is it different from other package specs?

Comment: I've only used conda, anaconda and miniconda a small amount, and I've read thru the source. That said, a `meta-package` is not any different than any other package in conda.  If you look at the spec file for anaconda, you are going to see it has one file, and a large number of dependencies.  I'm not sure what other metapackages are available, other than the `anaconda` package.

Comment: A meta-package just means that it doesn't have any files of its own. All it is is a bunch of dependencies on a bunch of other packages. Since conda always installs dependencies, `conda install anaconda` is a shorthand for installing all those packages.